# How to install tf-agents in anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I'm relatively new to Python and up to now my projects have only required me to use packages already available in Anaconda. I'm trying to do some reinforcement learning using tensorflow, and to do so I must download tf-agents, a package not automatically available in conda.
Tensorflow offers this information: https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/overview#installation
and the Github repository is: https://github.com/tensorflow/agents

I'm using Python 3.8.3, Tensorflow 2.1.0

I'm not sure if I should create a new environment different specifically for reinforcement learning or if there won't be any issues with package dependencies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there is a two-part answer to your question

1. in the cmd.exe window just enter 'pip install tf-agents

but you have to do more to make it usable:

2. you have to upgrade to tensorflow 2.3 to solve conflicts in the dependencies